# C# variable in a function become randomly not available

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I'm not really sure if I will be able to explain this behavior but I'll try. I have a program like a dashboard where some graph modules are initialized at startup, each module has a sole purpose to show a graph has a function passed to it which determine the data shown.
The module building (initializing each module type with the corresponding function) is handled in a separate thread using Task. But randomly some of these functions stop working and the List with the data stop being available as if it was never declared.

This is one of the functions, keep in mind it's kind of random which one throws this error, but one of these will always throw an exception. I really can't track down what could cause this behavior I thought about the resources being deleted by other thread but this List is created at startup and only passed and used as a reference. And nowhere in the program I ever reset this list. The same code work in other project and while debugging step by step... I'm really out of tracks to follow

```cs
  private static IEnumerable<ICompositeValue> GroupEvent(IEnumerable<Event> events, DateTime referenceDate, Month month)
        {

            List<ICompositeValue> Values= new List<ICompositeValue>();
    
            foreach (Days day in (Giorni[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Days)))
            {
                if (day != Giorni.Sunday)
                    if (events== null) return null; //this was tried to catch the exception
                    Values.Add(new ICompositeValue()
                    {
                        Argument = day.ToString(),
                        Valore = event.Count(x => (int)x.DDB_APDATA.Value.DayOfWeek == (int)day && (int)x.DDB_APDATA.Value.Month == (int)month && x.DDB_APDATA.Value.Year == referenceDate.Year)

                    }); ;
            }


            return valori;
        }
```

[As shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOfTJ.png) Visual Studio can't even evaluate the List value as if it was never declared

Can someone point me in the right direction?

**Thanks to everyone!**

I just wanted to thank those who tried to help me.

I still didn't get why the debugger acted the way it did since it showed me "x" was null not the inside property, but I managed to track down the problem. I noticed the object mapping from the DataTable was acting strange with the DateTime type variable and indeed something returned null from time to time

Comment: Your `List` is a red herring. Look at `x.DDB_APDATA`. The current code assumes `.Value` will always succeed, which it likely does not because you have `null` values in your data. Consider using something like `x.DDB_APDATA?.DayOfWeek` instead (and then don't cast to `int`).

Comment: I tried your solution but it kept saying tath x was null end events still cant be evaluated, i of course changed all the other variable to the nullable one

Comment: Unfortunately all we have to go on is that you have a `NullReferenceException` somewhere. Debugging your code is something only you can do, we can't do that merely by your vague description of the program. The only thing that's fairly certain is that what's happening probably isn't random, just hard to pin down. Try creating a [mre]; in the process of simplifying and rewriting you may solve the bug as well.

Comment: `events.Count` instead of `event.Count`

Comment: Yes i do not really think it is random, maybe I'm getting off track focusing on what visualstudio think is the problem, i was checking if someone had other insights

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jeroen Mostert has suggested it seems like some property in your lambda is unexpectedly null. The reason `events` is not available is because your debugger context is inside the lambda.

```
x => (int)x.DDB_APDATA.Value.DayOfWeek == (int)day && (int)x.DDB_APDATA.Value.Month == (int)month && x.DDB_APDATA.Value.Year == referenceDate.Year
```

So one of either `x`, `DDB_APDATA`, or `Value` will likely be null.

Comment: Didn't think about lambda context..  but now tath you said it like this it makes a lot more sense. But why does the debugger shows me x is null while events do not contain any null results?

Comment: Perhaps i should try a slower version using some nested foreach cycle just to track down what the issue could be